# Get Value of Column Whose Name is Result of Second Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with many of columns. Each represents a specific "scenario" for the data it represents. Looks something like this:

```
id | col1   | col2   | col3   | col4    | col5    
---+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------
1  | 1200   | 100    | 1200   | 10000   | 1300   
2  | 100    | 1400   | 2300   | 1200    | 900     
3  | 3300   | 1200   | 400    | 600     | 12000
```

I have another table that stores entities and a column where I store this entitiy's default scenario. Looks something like this:

```
id | city       | state | default_scenario 
---+------------+-------+-------------------
1  | Miami      | FL    | col3
2  | Detroit    | MI    | col2
3  | New York   | NY    | col1
```

I'd like to fetch results from the second table and return the value from the first table, according to what the `default_scenario` of the row is, as an extra column in the results.

I'm thinking this can be done with a `JOIN` but how could I use the value of a row as the column name of another, in the same query, without using PHP?

Is this even possible?

The query I'm trying to make would return this:

```
id | city       | state | default_scenario | scenario_data
---+------------+-------+------------------+--------------- 
1  | Miami      | FL    | col3             | 1200
2  | Detroit    | MI    | col2             | 1400
3  | New York   | NY    | col1             | 3300
```

Comment: you can't with SQL  .. directly .. you must use dinamic sql  (server side generated  sql code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in one query. Best you can do is:

- Use two queries
- Get the column names from the first query result
- Dynamically generate second query based on those column names

However, if you can change the db design, I would advise to extract out `scenarios` into separate table and add `scenario_id` in first tables instead of using different columns, i.e.:

```
id  |  scenario_id  | value
1   |       3       | 1200  
2   |       2       | 1400
```

Comment: Would this make queries slower? Only reason I'm asking is because I have ~70,000 different entities, each with 63 different scenarios. That would make ~4,410,000 rows in the table (under the design you're suggesting). This data also increases by about 650.000 twice each year. In the long run, the rows could reach 1bil+

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988915/mysql-creating-rows-vs-columns-performance) SO answer. With the above design, it will be normalized and easy to query (In the existing design, if you want to add let's say 20 more scenarios, you will end up creating 20 new columns which will be difficult to maintain in the long run).